# AOT compilation fails, unexpected value 'null' in AppModule

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I'm trying to get the AOT compilation in angular working, but I'm getting this error:

Unexpected value 'null' declared by the module 'AppModule

I am importing PrimeNg modules ,  AGgrid an ng2-adal. 
I have changed the ng2-adal export, so that it is explicit, but I can't find any other potential causes for this error. 
Question: Does anybody know what the real error is? If not, is it possible to get the ngc compiler to emit more verbose information?.

Comment: Looking at commit [9522cb](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/f6f24e7a82174ca4597c4611802e34a3f99522cb) you can use the  --verbose flag

Comment: Thanks Abdel, I have already tried that, but it gives no extra information :(

Comment: Can you share minimal reproduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error seems to be related to **ngc** template code generation. I had to configure ngc such that it skips template code generation using the angularCompilerOptions inside my **tsconfig.aot.json** like so:

```
{ 
  "compilerOptions": { ... }
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
      "skipTemplateCodegen": true
  }
}
```

Also make sure you comply with the requirements for AOT mentioned e.g. here: https://medium.com/@isaacplmann/making-your-angular-2-library-statically-analyzable-for-aot-e1c6f3ebedd5

I ran into the same issue because I was importing a default export, which is not allowed when you go for AOT. Replace all your default exports by named exports. After that you can then reactivate template code gen.